# Only able to get specific columns with Supabase and Next.js

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I'm only able to fetch certain columns out of my database. I'd like to get every row out of my table, but when I select all, nothing is returned. My table (shows) has 9 columns. I just created the table so there is only one row of data.

Here is example of code that works:

```
const supabase = createClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY);


let { data: shows, error } = await supabase.from('shows').select('city')
console.log(shows);
```

This logs `[ { city: 'Denver' } ]`

However, if I try to query all rows as per the Supabase documentation:

```
let { data: shows, error } = await supabase.from('shows').select()
console.log(shows);
```

It logs an empty array. Some documentation states I should put '*' in the select method, but that doesn't do anythin either. How can I get my data row by row with data from every column? I'm wanting to iterate over each row and display some information about each show.

Comment: You must have changed some settings within your Supabase instance. Have you fiddled with column level security? Do you remember any other settings that could cause this?

Comment: @dshukertjr I just set the table up, so I haven't changed any base settings. I went back through the account and database settings but didn't see anything that could cause this. Calling specific columns of data only returns those columns from the first entry as well, not from all rows.

Comment: Fixed it by calling `supabase.from('shows').select(' ')` instead. I have no clue why this worked as it's not consistent with the documentation at all.